# Use of the Java Vuforia APIs requires initalization via the com.vuforia.Vuforia class

Tags: java, android, vuforia

I am Always getting the Error and it Always say Use of the Java Vuforia APIs requires initalization via the com.vuforia.Vuforia class.
I don't Know How To initialize.Can Any One Help me Thank in Advance.
The Line Where I get Error is `CameraDevice.getInstance().init();`

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the Vuforia lifecycle steps according to their sample? If you haven't, I strongly recommend that.

There are mandatory steps in the initialization, each must be called when the previous one is finished. According to the error you are getting, I would guess you have not started with `Vuforia.init()`, or did not wait until it finishes.